# PointCloudLibrary project -> pcl/io/boost.h is causing problems: AccessViolationException

Tags: c++, boost, access-violation, point-cloud-library

my program is in C#, but this project is in C++.
I need to include `pcl/io/boost.h` in order to work with pointclouds.
My problem however is that I get an AccessViolationException error when initializing the class which includes it. It gives this explanation:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

it took me 2 days to figure out that the problem is with boost, but I had trouble with it before...

I run windows 7, VS 2010 x64 installed everything of pcl in x64.

Comment: And what is your question? If you found a possible bug with Boost, then you should report it to them instead.

Comment: I think boost c++ is native code, you'd better use a c++ dll project to wrap the functions you need, an use this dll in your C# project.

Comment: @ joachim, my question is how I can solve this, I doubt it's a boost bug. because that would mean no one could include boost and thus use pcl.

Comment: @neohope, I am sorry, I forgot to clearly specify that this is a C++ (dll)project in which the problem is, the error message is from C# though.

Comment: Danahi, I suggest you write a C++ project to test this dll first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it, turns out I could work around the error by looking at what I use from boost, (shared_array) and check if there is a library in the boost folder, instead of pcl/io/boost.

So for future references, if you get an error on a pcl library from a third party, check if u can use the third party library instead of the pcl/third party.